# Google voice speech recognition,beep(music) file location in android for rooted device

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on speech recognization where I am continuously listening to user input.I have made a loop through which it listens continuously.

Whenever Recognizer starts to listen it will play an audio file.playing of the audio is irritating and I don't need it.I want to remove that file so that it will not play that file again.

Comment: Are you writing spyware?

Comment: No Dear, I am writing the code for specific tab only which will be available only for car drivers. It not even contains a sim card neither internet so no chance of spyware or any hacking or leaking stuff.

Comment: Your answer may be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734868/muting-the-google-voice-recognition-beep-sound) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538752/how-to-mute-the-beep-sound-for-speechrecognizer) or even [here](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/issues/2).

Comment: It is not intended to be removed so easilly, so it's probably hardcoded into the service itself, generating the sound wave on the fly. There may be some short of option in the call to the API to tell it not to beep,though. Anyway, if you're root you should be able to install software to monitor disk access to check if it is right or not. I'm not android expert, so I can't give you a more specific answer. However, from the way you made your question, it really looks like you're trying to do some blackhat here, more detailed question whould help to get rid of the suspicious. Good luck!